# How to prove the completeness of $l^\infty_\mathbb{F}$?

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, banach-spaces, complete-spaces

Let $\mathbb{F}$ be $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$ and let $l^\infty_\mathbb{F}$ be the vector space of bounded sequences with the usual addition and scalar multiplication, equipped with the norm $\|\xi\|:=\sup_{j\in\mathbb{N}}|\xi_j|$. Then prove that $l^\infty_\mathbb{F}$ is complete.

Here is what I have done:

Let $\{\xi^{(i)}\}_{i\in\mathbb{N}}\subset l^\infty_\mathbb{F}$ be a Cauchy sequence. Then for $j\in\mathbb{N}$ we have that $\{\xi^{(i)}_j\}_{i\in\mathbb{N}}$ is Cauchy, thus we define $\xi^*$ by 
$$\xi^*_j=\lim_{i\to\infty} \xi^{(i)}_j.$$
First we have to show that $\xi^*\in l^\infty_\mathbb{F}$. By hypothesis there exists $N\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $$\|\xi^{(m)}-\xi^{(n)}\|<1 \qquad \text{whenever}\qquad m,n\ge N.$$
Thus if $n\ge N$ we have $$\|\xi^{(n)}\|\le\|\xi^{(N)}\|+\|\xi^{(n)}-\xi^{(N)}\|<\|\xi^{(N)}\|+1$$
and thus for $B:=1+\max_{1\le i\le N}\|\xi^{(i)}\|$ we see that $$\|\xi^{(n)}\|<B \qquad \text{for all}\qquad n\in\mathbb{N}.$$
Suppose that there exists $j\in\mathbb{N}$ with $|\xi^*_j|>B+1$. Then by construction there exists $K\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $$|\xi^*_j-\xi^{(k)}_j|<1 \qquad \text{whenever}\qquad k\ge K$$
and thus $$|\xi^{(K)}_j|\ge |\xi^*_j|-|\xi^*_j-\xi^{(k)}_j|>B$$
which is a contradiction. Thus $\xi^*$ is bounded i.e. $\xi^*\in l^\infty_\mathbb{F}$. Now I'm not able to show that $$\xi^{(i)}\overset{i\uparrow\infty}{\to}\xi^*$$
because I don't see how to control $|\xi^*_j-\xi^{(i)}_j|$ for infinitely many $j$ at once. How to do it?

Please give only hints.

Comment: As a first hint, note you don't have to control infinitely many $j$ at once. You only have to control the index where $sup$ occurs. Granted, the index where the sup occurs between the difference of $\xi^{(i)} - \xi^{(j)}$ changes as the $i, j$ vary, but this should at least give you some ideas.

Comment: @xyzzyz thanks for the hint, it was a perfect mix of impreciseness and essentiality :)

Comment: I'm really happy to hear that :)

Comment: I am sure this Q has appeared here before. A search by keyword(s) should find it for you.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to the comment of xyzzyz I found the following proof. Let $\varepsilon>0$, then there exists $N\in\mathbb{N}$ such that
$$
\|\xi^{(m)}-\xi^{(n)}\|<\frac{\varepsilon}{4} \qquad\text{whenever}\qquad m,n\ge N.
$$
Furthermore there exists $j\in\mathbb{N}$ such that
$$
\|\xi^{*}-\xi^{(N)}\|-\frac{\varepsilon}{4}<|\xi^{*}_j-\xi^{(N)}_j\|\le\|\xi^{*}-\xi^{(N)}\|.
$$
Finally there exists $M\in\mathbb{N}$ such that
$$
|\xi^{*}_j-\xi^{(m)}|<\frac{\varepsilon}{4} \qquad\text{whenever}\qquad m\ge M.
$$
Let $m=\max\{M,N\}$. Thus, if $n\ge N$ we have
$$
\|\xi^{*}-\xi^{(n)}\|\le\|\xi^{*}-\xi^{(N)}\|+\|\xi^{N}-\xi^{(n)}\|<|\xi^{*}_j-\xi^{(N)}_j|+\frac{\varepsilon}{4}+\frac{\varepsilon}{4}\le|\xi^{*}_j-\xi^{(m)}_j|+|\xi^{(m)}_j-\xi^{(N)}_j|+\frac{\varepsilon}{2}<\\\frac{\varepsilon}{4}+\|\xi^{(m)}-\xi^{(N)}\|+\frac{\varepsilon}{2}<\frac{\varepsilon}{4}+\frac{\varepsilon}{4}+\frac{\varepsilon}{2}=\varepsilon
$$
And thus
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\xi^{(n)}=\xi^*.
$$